# Не присваивается переменная из url

Tags: php, html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="success.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" <?php echo 'value="'.$price. '"'; ?>>
    <input type="hidden" name="title" <?php echo 'value="'.$title. '"'; ?>>
    <input type="hidden" name="year" <?php echo 'value="'.$year. '"'; ?>>
    <input type="hidden" name="spec" <?php echo 'value="'.$spec. '"'; ?>>
    <input type="hidden" name="closes" <?php echo 'value="'.$closes. '"'; ?>>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Имя</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone">Телефон</label>
        <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Заказать</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Первая страница, переменная со значением, при передачи на вторую не принимает значение.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$spec = $_POST['spec'];
$closes = $_POST['closes'];
$price = $_POST['price'];


$address = "test@gmail.com";

$article = "Защита картера двигателя";

$mes = "$article
Имя: $name
Телефон: $phone
Характеристики:
Марка: $title
Год: $year
Особенности: $spec
Покрывает $closes
Цена: $price";

$sub="Заказ обратного звонка!";
$send = mail ($address,$sub,$mes, "Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8
");
?>
```

Переменная price не принимает значение

Comment: Что значит не принимает? Кого именно не принимает? Непонятно ничего

Comment: @andreymal не принимает значение переменная $price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы понять, что происходит в вашем собственном коде, вам надо освоить некоторые приёмы отладки.

1. Научитесь пользоваться инструментами разработчика в браузере (обычно открывается по нажатию `f12`). Там есть инспектор HTML (вкладка Инспектор), который поможет подсмотреть, что находится в скрытых полях формы и есть лог сетевых запросов (вкладка Сеть), где можно посмотреть что именно у вас отправилось на сервер в теле HTTP-запроса.
2. `var_dump` -- функция PHP, которая позволяет заглянуть в переменную. Набрав `var_dump($_POST);` вы увидите, что у вас в этом массиве (в том числе и ключи, вероятно price там будет, но равен он пустой строке).

И ещё один совет для вас. Не выводите HTML c помощью php (я имею ввиду `echo ' value="..."'`). Вставляйте только значения и обязательно экранируйте их (почитайте про [XSS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3)): `<input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($price) ?>">` (небольшой бонус: шорттэг `<?=` работает всегда, а `;` перед закрывающим дескриптором можно опустить, это сделает ваши шаблоны более читаемыми).

Answer (score 1):

может $_POST попробуй)

```
<form ... method="post">
...
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Comment: @angularva ничего не поменялось, переменная $price не принимает значение